# Installing Windows 7 on notebook with Windows 8 pre installed?

Tags: windows-8, uefi, dell-inspiron, gpt

I have just acquired a Dell Inspiron 7720 with Windows 8 pre installed. I want to remove Windows 8 and install Windows 7 in it. Windows 8 is installed in the C: partition which is in GPT style. There are 2 other partitions that seem to be related to Recovery. I don't care about the data in C: but I don't want to lose what's in Recovery. All partitions are in the same physical disk, which has 1TB of total space.

What I tried to do was to go into BIOS, change boot from UEFI to Legacy and boot from my Windows 7 DVD. The installation process then complained that Windows 7 could not be installed in C: because it is a GPT partition.

In my google searches I learned that Windows 7 can be installed in a GPT partition if I enable UEFI in the BIOS and then boot from the Windows 7 DVD in UEFI mode. However, I have no idea how to boot from the Windows 7 DVD in UEFI mode.

Can anybody advise me on how do acomplish this?

Thanks!

P.S.: I did a search here in superuser before asking, but all I found was a thread teaching how to get to the bios configuration screen. I am able to do that, my problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The recovery partition tends to only contain a backup of windows 8, which can be downloaded from microsoft anytime. Is there a reason you want to keep it?

Comment: I wanted to keep the Recovery so I could reset the notebook to its initial settings in case the installation of Windows 7 went wrong.

Comment: As I saw in the answer comments, you are unable to boot from a dvd? How about USB? You could try launching a partition manager and reformatting C:

Comment: @Satoh: Would you care to enlighten us as to how someone who got Win8 pre-installed on a new PC can download it from MS any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the Dell 7520 (15R SE)

You need to go to the `UEFI` with <kbd>F2</kbd> and set the option `Load Legacy Option ROM` to `true`.

Now Windows 7 still uses UEFI, but UEFI loads the old VGA BIOS ROM which allows the installation of older Operating systems.

Comment: I didn't get to try this, as I did something different before seeing your answer. I turned on legacy boot in the BIOS and proceeded with the installation of Windows 7. When choosing the drive where I wanted to install Windows, I striked shift+f10 and cleaned my disk in the command prompt. For future reference, the commands I ran were: DISKPART; then LIST DISK; then SELECT x, where x was the number of my drive on the list; then CLEAN. I will however select this answer as the solution, since your problem seems to be very related to mine and you say it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: ok, *clean* removed all partitions and you've now installed Win7 in BIOS mode with MBR partition. But nice to see that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with that particular system and UEFI/BIOS, generally the steps would be:

- Enable UEFI
- Disable Secure Boot as Windows 7 does not support it
- Boot from the DVD - depending on the BIOS, the boot devices may show both legacy and UEFI options in the boot menu; make sure to select the UEFI version if that's the case.

Comment: My problem is exactly in the "boot from dvd part". If I shift+restart windows and choose the boot menu option, I'm presented with a black screen with the options "UEFI Boot" and "Other options". Under the "UEFI Boot" I have 3 selectable options, which are exactly: "Windows Boot Manager", "Windows Boot Manager", "Windows Boot Manager" and then finally "+Network Boot". Choosing any of them won't boot from the dvd.